# Check if the single source shortest path between two nodes is unique

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

Given an unweighted and undirected graph, how does one check whether there is a unique shortest path or more than one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Is it possible to count the number of shortest paths from the source to *each* vertex you encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a modified version of [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (I will call it modBFS) algorithm which return the shortest path between two nodes, the modification consists in marking the first node you visit(excluding the starting node) so the next time you call the algorithm it will not be visited, then you call modBFS again but this time the node that modBFS previously mark (that was the first node you visit) will not be visited so if there is another path between the nodes it will be returned (mind that it will be returned the shortest path again), you can simply check if the distances are the same. Then you can repeat this marking the second node you vist, then the third and so on, but remember to keep a copy of the first path you get because you need it to know which node you have to mark, as pseudocode

```
modBFS(start_node,end_node){
    path=BFS(start_node,end_node)
    for i=0 to path.length
        path[i].mark=0
        path1=BFS(start_node,end_node)
        if path1.lenght == path.lenght 
            return true
        path[i].mark=1
    return false
```

BFS will only visit the nodes if path[i].mark is ugual to 1